# how open *.dat database file, all files begin with "vdat"

Tags: ios, database, fmdb

I get some database files from iOS app, the filename like *.dat, I try to open them use textedit, or hex editor.i got messy code, all files begin with the word "vdat".some keys as follows:

1. file's name like "*.dat"
2. this is database files
3. I got them from iOS app
4. all files begin with "vdat", then follow some messy code
5. this iOS app use FMBD.framwork

**Q:how I can open this database files?**

**the files image here:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

".dat" its "Data".

No one software can support all .dat
because maybe its picture,music or movie.

Comment: this is database file,SQL or others

Comment: you can try use TextEdit open it.

Comment: Or maybe its MSSQL

Comment: maybe you can try to open with sqlite browser? http://sqlitebrowser.org/